# Python: plot histogram, where y values are less than 1

Tags: python, data-science

I have a task, where I have to display plot and histogram in same graph for Rayleigh Distribution 
(which never reaches 1 on Y axis, for me highest point is 0.30).

I have an array of x (linear space from 0 to 10), and calculated array of y (calculated from Rayleigh function with two arguments 1,5 and 2).

I can plot it easily. But cannot display a histogram, as histogram never takes values less than 1 (as x for histogram is how often value of some x range is present on y scale).

Could you please advise something?

Here is the code sample:
(I think I have to calculate x occasions on y somehow, right? That is what I miss?)

## Using Distribution of Rayleigh: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.stats import rayleigh

RAYLEIGH_LOW_LIMIT = 0
RAYLEIGH_HIGH_LIMIT = 10
RAYLEIGH_ARG_1 = 0.7
RAYLEIGH_ARG_2 = 2


# Part 1: Make selection of size 1000
# Build histogramm and theoretical density
selection = np.linspace(RAYLEIGH_LOW_LIMIT, RAYLEIGH_HIGH_LIMIT, num=1000)
y = rayleigh.pdf(selection, RAYLEIGH_ARG_1, RAYLEIGH_ARG_2)
plt.plot(selection, y, "r-",  label="Density")

plt.hist(selection, bins=10, density=True, label="Histogram", rwidth=0.1)

plt.show() # to display plot
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, is it possible to show what you've tried so far? That will help people work from the same frame of reference. Also, what library are you using to plot? Thanks!

Comment: In order to create a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), could you provide the code you tried?

Comment: I played around with this a bit, but don't quite understand what you're trying to do here. Histograms in Matplotlib will happily draw sub-1 values in histograms. You can see an example of this on the [scipy.stats.rayleigh documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rayleigh.html), so I don't think that's your problem. It looks like you may not be passing the correct values to `rayleigh.pdf`, though based on that documentation above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to show histograms of the Rayleigh distribution on which you superimpose a line representing the distribution.
If so you need to generate some values for the histograms since, linspace, is just the range of x values.  "linspace" is not directly something useful for the histogram.
To generate values that are useful for the histogram you can use the following Montecarlo approach (that you MUST append to your code because "y", for instance, is defined in your code).

```
import random

maxy=max(y)
lval=[]
for i in range(10000):
    ## pick a random y belonging to selection
    xv=random.choice(selection)
    yv=random.random()*maxy
    yral=rayleigh.pdf(xv, RAYLEIGH_ARG_1, RAYLEIGH_ARG_2)
    if(yv<=yral):
       lval.append(xv)
plt.plot(selection, y, "r-",  label="Density")
plt.hist(lval, bins=10, density=True, label="Histogram", rwidth=0.1)
```

The resulting plot is the following:

[image]

Take in mind that this is an approximation.

Another possible solution (I just checked the manual) when the generator is availble is to call rvs.

```
r=rayleigh.rvs(loc=RAYLEIGH_ARG_1, scale=RAYLEIGH_ARG_2, size=1000)
plt.plot(selection, y, "r-",  label="Density")
plt.hist(r, bins=10, density=True, label="Histogram", rwidth=0.1)
```

Comment: I found a solution thanks to Fabrizio and  Gavin. What I had to to do was to build a histogram was to call rvs function with same location and scale parameters, I was using to create a pdf function.